# Location of the Windows10 logon soundfile?

Tags: audio, login

I am seeking the file location of the sound that plays at the Windows10 logon screen.

I have looked in the "C:\Windows\Media" folder but can't seem to find it.  The most likely candidate, "Windows Logon.wav" is not it.

In case there is any doubt, I am referring to this sound:
https://youtu.be/HrPRtYvCvZI?t=32
(if that doesn't link to the exact time then it's 32 secs into the video)

Does anyone know the filepath to this soundfile? Thanks.

EDIT
I have checked every sound event that is defined in my current Windows sound scheme and none correspond to the sound I hear at the login screen. There is a checkbox for playing a sound at system startup but it doesn't allow you to change the actual soundfile or, crucially, tell you what / where it is.

I have also checked "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes" in case it was there, but no luck.

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't have a sound file that plays by default, at least none that I've ever heard. The sound you reference is from Windows 7/Vista. I have noticed, however, that certain Windows 10 installs retain that sound, but I think it's from systems that were updated from 7 to 10 and not through a clean install of 10. The sound you are looking for *should* be "Windows Startup.wav", but on my Windows 10 install it's just a 0 second file with no sound.

Comment: I agree. Look in Control Panel, Sounds to see if you (author) can identify the sound you mean. There is none on 3 machines here.

Comment: @Sam Forbis, that's odd. It was bought new in 2018 so should have been a clean Win10 machine. I did however import my Win8 PC's desktop theme, but if you see the EDIT in the OP I have investigated that. This file must be somewhere!
John, thanks for the suggestion but as noted in the OP EDIT, no joy.